# How not to save images in cache

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to save images using Camera in angular but the image always saves in the cache folder off my app :

http://localhost/_app_file_/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/my_image.jpeg

Here is the code to take a picture :

```
image: any = '';

async openCam() {
  const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
  };

  try {
    const imageData = await this.camera.getPicture(options);
    return this.image = (window as any).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imageData);
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle error
    if (JSON.stringify(err) !== '"No Image Selected"') {
      alert('error ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code to save and get the image :

```
async saveItem(item, value, secondValue) {
  this.nativeStorage.setItem(item, { one: value, two: secondValue })
    .then(() => console.log('Stored item!'))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error storing item', error));
}

async getItem(item) {
  return await this.nativeStorage.getItem(item);
}
```

I want to be able to store the image in the file of the app not in the cache
Ty for your responses

Comment: If you don't want to store data in a cache then don't use a plugin that stores data in a cache! Use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file instead of NativeStorage.

Comment: I may have explain badly on this one. The function getPicture() is saving the image in cache and so the imageData is pointing to the cache.